# Lost in the world of VPN

Tags: linux, debian, networking, vpn

**The Q.**
If i have a server, is it possible to have that server with a VPN connection, while simultaneously having an entirely separate connection to be able to SSH to from client machine.

**The Why.**
I have an Ubuntu 14.4 Server (no-gui) with a variety of mounted drives. 
I wish to maintain remote ssh access to the server, but for select applications installed, to have them operate through the VPN.

**The Tried.**
I have tried OpenVPN alongside PIA and although in appearance, a connection is made and authorized, the server losing all connectivity and ultimately requires a reboot to open up the ability to use the system remotely again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you configured your client to push all the traffic through VPN, so you lost connection to the server after that.

Check your client configuration

Answer (score 1):

At home a I have a Lamobo R1 (ARM with 5 gigabit ethernet ports) with Jessie Debian; I have an IPsec VPN configured with [StrongSwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StrongSwan).

The server acts as router and firewalls too, with iptables.

All accesses from the outside have to come via the VPN, *including* ssh.

In addition, the IPsec VPN is configured as such to be compatible with the native VPN clients of OS/X and iOS. https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IOS_(Apple)

Since you have a VPN, I do recommend for ssh to work only inside the VPN, it will be one less service exposed.

Also in the VPN, I do route my private/RFC 1918 network addresses via the VPN; all communications done with any service via the machine public address with not go through the VPN.

At work, I do have corporate firewalls, and then behind firewalls I do have several VPN technologies, namely Cisco, FreeBSD (pfSense) and Linux (strongswan).

Answer (score 0):

If I  understand correctly, you wish to remotely access your sever, meaning from outside your home/office, correct?

In addition, you also want your server to be connected to a VPN at the same time.

For starters, is your server behind a firewalled router at least? Or is it directly connected to the Internet (not a very secure way of doing things)?

Based on the information you have provided, I recommend that you have the server behind a firewalled router (such as OPNsense), and enable a VPN server on the firewall for incoming connections. You do not want to open the SSH port to the outside world.

Basically, you separate the two VPN services. Your server connects to PIA using the PIA configuration files through OpenVPN, and it is still accessible on the local network through SSH, as well as from the outside only if you connect to your firewall through the VPN server running on it. This does not require you to connect the firewall to PIA, and it does not cost a subscription to a VPN provider. You are providing your own VPN service to clients connecting to your server.

Incoming connections will go through the IP address of your ISP, not through PIA. PIA will only be used by your server in this scenario for outgoing connections.